# Scaling Pattern Fills in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, patterns

I would like to give an object a striped fill, where the stripes are thin and dense. I chose "stripes 1 : 2" from the Pattern Fill menu but the pattern was too coarse. Online help suggested that after selecting the object, handles for controlling the scale, orientation and origin of the pattern should appear. However, I could not find them so for now I'm relying on scaling the objects up without resizing the pattern, then scaling down while resizing the pattern.

Is there a better way to do this, or did I miss a way to find the above-mentioned handles?

Answer (score 25):

OK, I think I know what's the problem here! Some times the handles are out of the document. You should double click the pattern to show all the handles available, then check the two handles attached to the origin point. Normally the origin point is at the center of the shape but sometimes Inkscape save / remember your work-space session preferences. This is something I disable in Inkscape Preferences to avoid this kind of issues and for better performance. Just try to find the origin point with the two handles attached to it.

Hope this help!

Comment: You are quite right: the handles were there all the time but they were at some distance away from the bounding box of the object. They were on the page boundary. I needed to zoom out to see them. For others with the same problem: Look at those instructions with images to understand it: http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Attributes-Fill-Stroke.html#Attributes-Patterns-Adjusting Or even better: Just try it with a new document and a test object with a test pattern (at least I didn’t know how to change pattern scale at all), that helped me.

Comment: Is this a bug? Why would they put those handles on the edge of the document?

Comment: Thank you for the explanations! I have one additional question: how to disable it in Inkscape preferences?

Comment: @mydoghasworms: I guess the handles are where the actual origin of the pattern is when it was defined.